# How to rerun a test in stack

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, haskell-stack

I have a project in stack with tests that I run with `stack test`. 
A test fails and the output says

```
...
  To rerun use: --match "/foo/must be 4/"
....
```

But how am I supposed to apply that?

`stack test --match "/foo/must be 4/"` yields `` Invalid option `--match` ``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--match "/foo/must be 4/` is supposed to be given as an argument to the compiled executable program running the test rather than Stack. Pass it to the executable by doing `stack test --test-arguments '--match "/foo/must be 4/"'` or `stack test --ta '--match "/foo/must be 4/"'`